# Spring MVC request not reaching Controller class

Tags: spring-mvc

I know this question has already been asked before, but none of the solutions mentioned there seems to be working for me.
I'm writing a Spring MVC web application. But my request is not reaching the controller class.
Here are the relevant files. 
Can anyone please help me by pointing out where I am going wrong? Thanks...

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>booksWorld</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath:**/*applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Declare a view resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver"   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"      xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.booksworld.controllers" />
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:**/*config.properties" />

<!-- <bean id="messageSource"     class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"     p:basename="resources/Messages" /> -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<bean id="transactionManager"    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-    ref="sessionFactory" />


<bean id="sessionFactory"     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.booksworld"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"     class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" 
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" >
</bean>

</beans>
```

My controller class

```
package com.booksworld.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class CommonController {

@RequestMapping("/proceed")
public String loadLoginPage() {
    System.out.println("we reached here");
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public String login() {
    return "abc";
}

}
```

index.jsp (the welcome jsp file)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO- 8859-1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Welcome All</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Hello World</p>

    <%response.sendRedirect("proceed.do"); %>
</body>

</html>
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sf" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Books World - Login</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <sf:form method="POST" action="login.do" modelAttribute="Login">

            <h3>Please enter your credentials</h3>
            Login Name<sf:input path="userName" />
            Password<sf:password path="password" />

            </br>
            </br>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
        </sf:form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

I'm developing in eclipse, and using Tomcat. the server log has no errors. Just the standard start-up log.

Please help me to point out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Try @RequestMapping(value="/login.do")

Comment: What are the URLs you are trying? Do you get a 404, or some other error?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified which URL you are hitting and what errors or output you are seeing so I will go by the files you have posted.  There seem to be at least a few problems with what you have posted.  I am assuming you are trying to access either `http://[server]:[port]/index.jsp` or `http://[server]:[port]/`.

**Problem 1**: When using an MVC framework you usually do not request web templates such as JSP files directly.  Therefore, your welcome file list in `web.xml` should not contain `index.jsp`.  It is more common to omit this section altogether.  Instead, you should add a request mapping to the controller class for the application root, such as:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home() { return "index"; }
```

Once you do this, you should be able to hit `http://[server]:[port]/` and get a response.

**Problem 2**: The file `index.jsp` redirects to the URL `proceed.do` but there is no mapping for this URL in your controller.  Instead, the controller has a mapping for the URL `proceed`.  May be there was some confusion with Struts when you were trying to configure the URL mappings.

**Problem 3**: The file `login.jsp` submits to `login.do` but there is no mapping for this URL.  Instead there is a mapping for `login`.  The form action should therefore be changed from `login.do` to `login`.

**Problem 4**: The form in `login.jsp` is bound to a model attribute called `Login` but the controller does not add any model object with that name.

**Problem 5**: The form in `login.jsp` is submitted using an HTTP POST but the controller does not specify this for the `login` method.  The default for controller methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` is HTTP GET so the `login` method will not be called when you submit the form.

**Problem 6**: The file `index.jsp` seems to be redundant as its sole purpose is to redirect to a different URL on the same server.  You will be better off with the following simplified controller code:

```
@Controller
public class CommonController {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String loadLoginPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("Login", new Login()); // Or something like this, which represents the actual model object that should collect the login information.

    return "login";
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/login")
  public String login(Login login) {
    // Use the login object to authenticate the user.

    return "abc";
  }
}
```

I would also recommend that you keep the lines

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.booksworld.controllers" />
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in the file `dispatcher-servlet.xml` as these lines are specific to your presentation layer.